# basic questions about US bond trading

Tags: united-states, trading, bonds

I'm new to the bond trading, but have some basic questions.

Let's suppose I want to buy the following bond today (11/6/2018)
[See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8zXp.png)

As you can see there, the maturity date of that bond is 11/30/2018. So does this mean after purchasing that bond today (11/6/2018), the bond will be automatically settled on 11/30/2018, and as a result of that, the correct amount of cash (i.e., the face value + coupon interest) will be deposited into my account?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but remember that you *also* must pay the amount of interest that has accrued since the *last* coupon (which is not reflected in the price), so effectively you'd only get 24 day's worth of interest (not the full semi-annual coupon)